# Can pointer casts that only change const-ness invoke undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I stumbled over some code that appears to be correct.
It is supposed to provide a public, immutable pointer, while keeping the modifiable non-const pointer private.

Strangely enough, this code broke on SN C++ Compiler (for PlayStation 3), but worked fine on GCC. On SN C++, `data` would point to bogus values, while `m_data` would work as intended.

Code in question:

```
#include <cstdint>

class Foo
{
   public:
      Foo() : data((const std::uint8_t* const&)m_data)
      {
         m_data = nullptr; // Set later in some other member function.
      }

      const std::uint8_t* const &data;

   private:
      std::uint8_t* m_data; 
};
```

Does this code invoke undefined behavior? As far as I know, casting to a reference like that will convert `(const std::uint8_t* const&)m_data` into `*reinterpret_cast<const std::uint8_t* const*>(&m_data)`.

Test cases:

```
Foo* new_foo() { return new Foo; }
```

and looking at the generated disassembly. Note that it is PowerPC 64-bit with 32-bit longs and pointers.

SN C++: `ps3ppusnc -o test-sn.o -O3 -c test.cpp`

```
0000000000000000 <._Z7new_foov>:
   0:   f8 21 ff 81     stdu    r1,-128(r1)     # ffffff80
   4:   7c 08 02 a6     mflr    r0
   8:   f8 01 00 90     std     r0,144(r1)      # 90
   c:   fb e1 00 78     std     r31,120(r1)     # 78
  10:   38 60 00 08     li      r3,8
  14:   3b e0 00 00     li      r31,0
  18:   48 00 00 01     bl      18 <._Z7new_foov+0x18>
  1c:   60 00 00 00     nop
  20:   2c 03 00 00     cmpwi   r3,0
  24:   41 82 00 38     beq     5c <._Z7new_foov+0x5c>
  28:   30 81 00 70     addic   r4,r1,112       # 70
  2c:   93 e3 00 04     stw     r31,4(r3) <-- Set m_data to r31 (0).
  30:   60 7f 00 00     ori     r31,r3,0
  34:   90 83 00 00     stw     r4,0(r3)  <-- Set data to r4 (r1 + 112 (On stack)?!)
  38:   63 e3 00 00     ori     r3,r31,0
  3c:   e8 01 00 90     ld      r0,144(r1)      # 90
  40:   7c 08 03 a6     mtlr    r0
  44:   eb e1 00 78     ld      r31,120(r1)     # 78
  48:   38 21 00 80     addi    r1,r1,128       # 80
  4c:   4e 80 00 20     blr
```

GCC 4.1.1: `ppu-lv2-g++ -o test-gcc.o -O3 -c test.cpp`

```
0000000000000000 <._Z7new_foov>:
   0:   38 60 00 08     li      r3,8
   4:   7c 08 02 a6     mflr    r0
   8:   f8 21 ff 91     stdu    r1,-112(r1)     # ffffff90
   c:   f8 01 00 80     std     r0,128(r1)      # 80
  10:   48 00 00 01     bl      10 <._Z7new_foov+0x10>
  14:   60 00 00 00     nop
  18:   7c 69 1b 78     mr      r9,r3
  1c:   38 00 00 00     li      r0,0
  20:   39 63 00 04     addi    r11,r3,4 <-- Compute address of m_data
  24:   78 63 00 20     clrldi  r3,r3,32        # 20
  28:   90 09 00 04     stw     r0,4(r9) <-- Set m_data to r0 (0).
  2c:   e8 01 00 80     ld      r0,128(r1)      # 80
  30:   38 21 00 70     addi    r1,r1,112       # 70
  34:   91 69 00 00     stw     r11,0(r9) <-- Set data reference to m_data.
  38:   7c 08 03 a6     mtlr    r0
  3c:   4e 80 00 20     blr
```

Comment: What does "happened to break" mean?

Comment: Agree with Rook, can you provide a minimal test-case that exhibits the broken behaviour?

Comment: You are using `m_data` in initialization of `data`, but at that point, m_data is still uninitialized.

Comment: You know, I don't think I've ever seen anything quite like `const type* const&` before. It feels like it would be safer (as it would involve less magic) and saner (for people reading it) to use an accessor function that returned a `const std::uint8_t*` instead, surely?

Comment: g++ 4.5 compiles this *without* the cast at all. Are you sure it's needed?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Added test case for GCC/SN PS3.

Comment: Are you copying this type at any time?  The compiler generated copy constructor will _not_ work correctly.  You should either provide one which is correct, or inhibit copy.

Comment: @Rook Using an accessor would certainly be preferable: more idiomatic, more readable, and more natural.

Comment: @JamesKanze: the compiler generated copy ctor is suppressed by the reference data member, isn't it? So the questioner is *not* copying the type without implementing one.

Comment: @SteveJessop No.  The reference only prevents the definition of a compiler generated copy assignment operator.  The copy constructor is still generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to fight through the spec language in 4.4/4 (of C++11), but I believe that 3.10/10 permits this. It says that object may be aliased as "a type similar to the dynamic type of the object".

In this case, the dynamic type of the object is `std::uint8_t*`, and the similar type is `const std::uint8_t* const`. I think. Check 4.4/4 for yourself.

[Update: C++03 doesn't mention "similar" types in 3.10/15, so it may be that you're in trouble on C++03, which presumably is what SNC works with.]

There's a second thing that needs to be checked, which is whether it's OK to initialize the reference `data` by binding it to an object that hasn't been initialized yet (`m_data`). Intuitively that seems OK, since the reference to the uninitialized `m_data` is never converted to an rvalue. It's easily fixed, anyway.